# Does the acceleration formula from dynamics apply in all cases?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics

Can the formula for acceleration $$a=\frac{F}m $$ (where $a$=acceleration, $F$=force ,$m$=mass) be used in all cases ? Or is it an isolated formula used only for some cases ?

Answer (score 6):

This is Newton's 2nd law of motion and It's valid only in [intertial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_frame_of_reference#:%7E:text=An%20inertial%20frame%20of%20reference%20is%20one%20in%20which%20the,straight%20line%20at%20constant%20speed.) frames of reference. In non inertial frames pseudo forces act on the system due to frame's acceleration. Find more about it [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/723604/why-exactly-is-newton-s-second-law-valid-only-in-non-accelerating-frames#:%7E:text=Because%20zero%20net%20force%20means,Thus%20breaking%20second%20Newton%20law.).

Answer (score 2):

Yes.I think this formula applies in all cases.
It is called Newton's second law:

```
            When a body is acted upon by a net force, the body's acceleration                                   
            multiplied by its mass is equal to the net force.
```

This means that the body will move in the direction in which the sum of all the forces acting on the body is working.The body will move with acceleration equal to force devided by mass.The bigger the force,the bigger the acceleration.The bigger the mass,the smaller the acceleration.And vice versa:Smaller force gives smaller acceleration and smaller mass allows bigger acceleration.
Let's take a body with some forces acting on it.[image: The body is a simple square on the ground with some blue arrows going in different directions.]
The arrows represent forces.Their effect is the same as if there was only one force,the sum of all the blue ones,called the net force.[image: There is now only one big red arrow.]
The body is accelerating in the same direction.It can also be decelerating,if it's moving in the opposite direction than the force is working.If the sum of all forces is zero,there's no net force and the body is still or moving at a constant speed.

The second Newton's law works for big and small bodies,including planets and atoms.

I think this is correct,but as I'm not a professional,I can't be sure.Check out other answers if they appear or do some research yourself!

Answer (score 0):

For a system of particles F=k m a_c where m is the total mass of the system and a_c is the center of mass, and k is a unit system dependent constant.
F is the total vector force applied on the system.

It IS general, with the following provisos:

1.All speeds are much less than the speed of light.

2.If a rationalized system of units is used k=1.

3. a is the vector acceleration defined as the time rate of change of velocity (not the scalar acceleration, defined as the time rate of change of speed)